# What are my options for having the RadioButtonList functionality of ASP.NET in WinForms?

Tags: winforms, webforms, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

Is this type of control only available in a 3rd-party library?  Has someone implemented an open source version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can include radio buttons in a grid, though that's more cumbersome than it needs to be.

Also, I don't think it'd be that hard to make your own control that creates the radio buttons dynamically using a flowlayout panel.